# How to place slide title in the center of the page in R Markdown?

Tags: css, r-markdown, presentation, ioslides

I would like to make a slide breaking between two sections by adding a blank slide with a short title in main title format (single #) in the center of it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create slides with no title and with classes `.blank-slide .flexbox .vcenter` and then create the slide title directly using `h1` tag. And then use css on `h1` tag under the `.blank-slide` class to make it look like title-slide title.

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
date: "2023-06-10"
css: style.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax.


## {.blank-slide .flexbox .vcenter}


<h1>Intro to Syntax</h1>


## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3


## {.blank-slide .flexbox .vcenter}

<h1>More Discussion</h1>
````

**style.css**

```css
.blank-slide h1 {
  font-size: 65px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  color: #515151;
}
```

[image: rendered output]